# Importing parent modules in complex directory structures?

Tags: python, python-2.7

How do I link the util.py file to the script.py file?

```
App
  Module
    __init__.py
    util.py
  Main
    __init__.py
    Dir1
      script.py
      __init__.py
    Dir2
      script.py
      __init__.py
```

Take this directory layout of my app. It's a bit more complex for requirement reasons to keep the scripts easily separated while sharing the same module across each script. However, it's difficult to find the correct way to import that module to each script due to directory hierarchy.

**Environment**

Python 2.7, Windows 10, 64Bit

Comment: by making them as modules.  create `__init__.py` in each directory. Not sure if you meant that

Comment: If you mean for main and dir, I did, just forgot it. I'll add it.

Comment: Yes , thats what i meant. does that solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Just add the root directory to the `PYTHONPATH`. Then you can use absolute imports as well as the relative ones.

```
# script.py
form Module.util import _
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, '.')
```

in your `Module.__init__.py` and then just import it in `script.py` with:

```
from Modules import util
```

Additionally you can define a `__all__ = []` variable in your `__init__` and then you can star import.